# Error: undefined local variable or method 'foo' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to find the needle in the haystack. I already received the dictionary with the two values and keys.

ruby haystack.rb

```
{"haystack"=>["D0zVh", "F1PFc", "j1WMn", "Ebz3k", "SE7gZ", "kOa7j", "0vCJb", "px18q", "NJSyl", "nRsOK", "T7t8F", "2jvwZ", "5414s", "q5z8U", "TI2Zm", "v4Bn9", "5dRcM", "M84vp", "8nQ0o", "OxEKw"], "needle"=>"v4Bn9"}
```

The first value, needle, is the string. The second value, haystack, is an array of strings. 
The next step is to tell the API where the needle is in the haystack array.

I need to post my result to "api/validateneedle", using the key token for my token, and the key needle for the integer representing where the needle is in the haystack array.

When I run this file, I get the following error:

```
haystack.rb:59:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `token' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm receiving this error message? I really appreciate any help/feedback!

```
token_info = {:token => "SVilLuY0OU"}

require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new("challenge.code2040.org")

# Sending json in body of http request
# Creating a request that will use the post http method 

require "json"

body = token_info.to_json

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/haystack")

# Setting the request body to be our json
request.body = body

# Storing my token in a variable
response = http.request(request)


# Printing my token to complete rest of assignment  
#Printing the body of the response
response_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)

puts response_hash["result"]

def getIndex(response)

    needle = response["result"]["needle"]
    haystack = response["result"]["haystack"]

    i = 0
    while i < haystack.length

        # if we find it, break the loop and return i
        if haystack[i] == needle
            return i.to_s
    end

    i += 1

end

    return "not found"

end

def sendIndex(token)
    response = getItems(token)
    index = getIndex(response)
    params = {'token' => token, 'needle' => index}
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/validateneedle")

end

sendIndex(token)
```

Comment: sendIndex(token) what is token?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory: on line 59, you are passing the argument `token` to the method `sendIndex`, but `token` isn't defined, neither as a method nor as a local variable.

Comment: I'm new to programming and am teaching myself. I don't know how to define 'token' to accomplish my goal. Can you help me please? Give more details?

Comment: @Daphne: methods are defined with `def`, local variables are defined with `=`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am trying to figure out how to send the index to the api/validateneedle and I really don't know how to proceed given your response.  Could you help me in terms of my end goal please?  Thanks!